# Vue.js & Laravel - How to retrieve input for comment edit

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am new to Vue.js.

I am making a comment and reply system.

Creating and Deleting a comment and reply are working fine.

I want to edit a comment. Editing without a retrieving a current comment is working fine.

Only problem is I don't know how to retrieve a current comment on edit field.

I think I need to insert `{{ comment.cotent }}` into somewhere in textarea or insert `getComment` method on `editComment` method but I don't know how to do it.

I am using Laravel and Vue.js 2 and Vue-resource.

```
<!-- This is a text area for write a comment. This works fine.  -->
<div class="" v-if="$root.user.authenticated">
  <textarea placeholder="Write a comment here!" class="form-control" v-model="content"></textarea>
  <div class="pull-right">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" @click.prevent="createComment">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Showing comments. This works fine. -->
<li class="media" v-for="comment in comments">
  <p>{{ comment.content }}</p>
</li>


<!-- Editing a comment without retrieving a current comment. This works fine but I want to retrieve a current comment!!!!   -->
<div class="" v-if="commentEditFormVisible === comment.id">
  <textarea class="form-control comment__input" v-model="commentEditBody"></textarea>
  <div class="pull-right">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" @click.prevent="editComment(comment.id)">Edit</button>
  </div>
</div>



<!-- script  -->
data() {
    return {
      comments: [],
      content: null,
      replyBody: null,
      replyFormVisible: null,
      commentEditBody: null,
      commentEditFormVisible: null,
    }
  },


  getComments() {
    this.$http.get('/blog/' + this.blogslug + '/comments').then((response) => {
      this.comments = response.body.data;

    });
  },


  editComment(commentId) {
    this.$http.put('/blog/' + this.blogslug + '/comments/' + commentId, {
      content: this.commentEditBody
    }).then((response) => {
      this.content = null;

    });
  },
```

Comment: to be clear; you are trying to edit a comment, at the same time having the comment on your edit fields right ?

Comment: Yes, I want to show a current comment on edit field when I click a edit button like I can do it on laravel. <textarea name="comment" id="comment"  class="form-control">{{ old('comment') ? old('comment') : $blog->comment}}</textarea>

Comment: you have to set up an edit method on your controller, select the comment from db and then compact it to the view blade. Show me your controller code.You need to use what is called form binding on Laravel